Expected maximum of a multivariable linear function over multiple samples

Suppose we have a linear function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, say, $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \alpha_i x_i$ with $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}, \forall i$.
We also have $n$ independent bernoulli random variables $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n$, where $y_i = 1$ with a given probability $p_i$, for each $i$
Now we independently sample the random variables for $s$ times, i.e., for $j = 1, 2, \ldots, s$, we obtain $(z_{j1}, z_{j2}, \ldots, z_{jn}) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $z_{ji} \sim y_i$
We evaluate $f$ on each list of sampled variables and collect the values $v_j := f(z_{j1}, z_{j2}, \ldots, z_{jn})$ for each $j \in [s]$
We then take the maximum of the $v_j$'s, i.e., we compute $z := \max_{j \in [s]} v_j$

Q: How can we compute, at least estimate $\mathbb{E}[z]$, the expected value of $z$?
Note: A simple upper bound is
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[z] 
&= \mathbb{E}[\max_{j \in [s]} v_j] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[\max_{j \in [s]} \sum_{i \in [n]} \alpha_i z_{ji}] \\
&\leq \mathbb{E}[\sum_{i \in [n]} \max_{j \in [s]} \alpha_i z_{ji}] \\
&= \sum_{i \in [n]} \mathbb{E}[\max_{j \in [s]} \alpha_i z_{ji}]] \\
&= \sum_{i \in [n], \alpha_i > 0} \alpha_i (1 - (1 - p_i)^s) + 
\sum_{i \in [n], \alpha_i < 0} \alpha_i p_i^s.
\end{align}
I am wondering whether we can obtain a tighter upper bound or any non-trivial lower bound.

It is related to one of my previous questions: Expected maximum of a multivariable function from sampling, but the previous question received no answer, so I tried to study a more specific case as described above.
